# is there a way to tag video files independent of any tool

Tags: windows, tags, adobe, metadata, windows-explorer

We are in the 21st century and still there is no good way to tag photos and videos? There is always a dependency on some tool... Is there no way to make the file autonomous with respect to its tags?

Video files, for example, are not friendly to tags. some video formats do not allow tagging at all. Some tools keep the meta data in their own external representation and when you copy the original file to some new destination, the meta data of the file in the destination is lost. Also this metadata may only be seen by this proprietary tool and is not seen by other tools (e.g. tagging by Adobe products are not visible/searchable in Windows Explorer)

Is there a universal way to tag **any file including video files** so that

1. searching for files having a certain tag is possible **in any tool**
2. when a file is copied, the tags are transferred with it
3. when the file is edited **in any tool** and re-saved, the tags are not lost...?

Answer (score 0):

There are no universal ways at this point, if there ever will be one.

Probaby the closest we got is file tagging provided by popular OSes based on a certain file systems' feature called '[forking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(file_system))'. By this means Windows and Mac provide an ability to easily add meta data (including keywords) to any file on the file system, without changing the file's content. One serious drawback of this feature is that it does not cross file-system's boundary, i.e. if you simply upload a file to the web, or copy it to a different type filesystem - the metadata will be lost. There are ways to copy such metadata but that requires consideration and use of appropriate tools.